# error: pathspec 'L3-start' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: javascript, git, vue.js, npm, vuejs3

just started the Real World Vue 3 course VueMastery offers and unfortunately I ran into a problem quite quickly.
I created a project as they said and now trying to checkout the L3-start branch they ask you to checkout to continue with the course, but I get this error:

```
error: pathspec 'L3-start' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

I saw people saying to use git fetch/add etc. but nothing works for me,
I'm preforming the git checkout in the project folder.
should I do it in a different folder maybe?
if not, what might be the problem?
thanks!

[image: Dirs & files]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I removed the image Thank you.

Comment: I think you should add the command you are running that is giving you that error.

Comment: As I said I'm trying to checkout, should've been more clear sorry about that.
the command I'm running is "git checkout L3-start"

Comment: Is the branch definitely supposed to exist on the remote?

Comment: In the video they say to create a project through the Vue CLI, then navigate to the project's location and use "git checkout L3-start" in terminal.
By that I understand that it suppose to work.
went through it a few times to check if I'm doing something wrong and it doesn't seem like it

Comment: Can you try entering `git ls-remote origin L3-start` to confirm that the branch exists on the remote? If you get nothing returned then the branch doesn't exist on the remote.

Comment: It appears that id doesn't exist that's the message I get :

"fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

what do I do in this situation?
thank you :)

Comment: It seems we may have found the issue. Can you enter `git remote -v` to see if you have a remote set up with a different name? If you get output then replace origin with whatever your remote is called. If you get no output then you will need to find the remote repository URL from VueMastery and add it to your local repository. See [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) for details on how to do that.